# Simple preceding-sibling select returns unexpected results

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I am trying to learn XPath/XQuery on BaseX. An XPath query returns some results that I cannot explain.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manual>
<chapter>
<section>
        <itemizedlist type="Ordered" mark="1">
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        <CWD>
            <para>1</para>
        </CWD>
        <para/>
        <CWD>
            <para>2</para>
        </CWD>
        <para/>
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        <CWD>
            <para>3</para>
        </CWD>
        <para/>
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                <para/>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        </section>
    </chapter>  
</manual>
```

XPath:

```
//CWD[preceding-sibling::itemizedlist[1]]
```

Expected result: the CWD elements immediately preceded by itemizedlist, hence:

```
<CWD>
    <para>1</para>
</CWD>
<CWD>
    <para>3</para>
</CWD>
```

Actual results:

```
<CWD>
    <para>1</para>
</CWD>
<CWD>
    <para>2</para>
</CWD>
<CWD>
    <para>3</para>
</CWD>
```

Why does the query return CWD 2, and how am I misusing the preceding-sibling axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `//CWD[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::itemizedlist]]` to check that the immediately preceding sibling element is an `itemizedlist` element.

Comment: To expand on this a little: the predicate `X[preceding-sibling::Y[1]]` tests whether a preceding sibling named Y exists (it actually tests whether the first preceding sibling named Y exists, but if any such siblings exists, then there must be a first one). By contrast the predicate `X[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Y]` finds the first preceding sibling element (with any name) and then tests whether it is named Y.